# Bootstrap and MVC Ajax Action links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, actionlink

In my app I'm using MVC with Bootstrap. Ajax Action links are used as navigation.

Example:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header"></div>
                <div class="buttons-container"></div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-nav">
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink( i, "Action", "AboutUs", new { title = i }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "mainDiv", OnComplete = "updateDivAboutUs"} )</li>
</ul></div> </div>
```

Everything works as expected, when I resize my browser these links are converted into "dropdown" but my main problem is after converting I lose Ajax options like update target and I have plain text on my page without css and anything.

Did anyone encounter this problem before and any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's Bootstraps responsive design. The resizing of your nav links to a dropdown box. removing the 'navbar-collapse' div should do the trick I guess.

Comment: I've already tried that but but then i have page that is resizing as suppose to but links stay and it gets all mixed up and not functional.